# Excel VBA Macro Axis Font Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, axis-labels

How can I tell the Axis to have a certain Font?

This is what I've got so far.
The last five lines are a recorded macro, doesn't work.
Excel highlights the line "`Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font`" yellow.

```
    With objChart.Chart
        .ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = False
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .HasLegend = False
        .HasTitle = False
        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleNone)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisNone)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone)
        .HasAxis(xlCategory) = True
'            With .Axis(xlCategory).Select
'                Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
'                    .BaselineOffset = 0
'                    .Name = "Arial"
'            End With
```

This is the recorded Macro:

```
Sub Macro_1()

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
        With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
            .BaselineOffset = 0
            .Name = "Times"
            .Size = 12
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a break on the last line of code below and put a watch on `ax` you can run the code then examine the various properties of `ax` in the Watches pane.  That's how I found `ax.TickLabels.Font.Name`...

```
Sub Macro_1()
    Dim cht As Chart, ax As Axis
    
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Set ax = cht.Axes(xlCategory)
    ax.TickLabels.Font.Name = "Times"
End Sub
```

In your posted code

```
With objChart.Chart
    .ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = False
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .HasLegend = False
    .HasTitle = False
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleNone)
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisNone)
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone)
    .HasAxis(xlCategory) = True
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Name = "Times" '<<###
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! And how can I put this piece of info into my actual macro? Can I somehow insert this after .HasAxis(xlCategory) = True?

Comment: `.Axis(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Name = "Times"`

Comment: Wow! So it doesn't work with ".Axis(...)", but ".Axes(...)" does the job! Even though ".HasAxis" needs to be with an "i", not "e". Thank you very much!

Comment: An `Axis` is not a collection

Comment: Oh, ok. So much to learn. Just started with some simple macros a few weeks ago. Now definitely hungry for more. Really need to get into the syntax basics.